# How Can Automatically Close Application Error Using batch Script

Tags: batch, batch-file

hi how can i automatically close this one when error prompt out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcaxP.png)

please see the link thanks

i've already done coding some  like this one

Title “GARY APP ERROR ”

:AppError
set PID=
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq WerFault.exe" /nh') do set PID=%%x
if not defined PID goto :Done
taskkill /f /pid %PID%
timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul
goto AppError

:Done
echo All dead.

but after that, it give's an error like that thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you correctly. The title implies that you want to close the error message that pops up, and you want to use the command line or a batch file to click on the "ok" button that the error message prompts you with.

If this is true then here is one method for doing that:

Go to [here](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and get the Nircmd utility.

Add the Nircmd utility to the current directory, or place it somewhere in the PATH.

From the command line (or from a batch script) run

`nircmd.exe dlg "" "" click ok`

and the message box will clear. I'm sure there are many other ways to do it, VBscript comes to mind, but maybe this will suit your needs.

Comment: thank you very much indeed it helps =)